# Update number of posts when attribute changed

Tags: block-editor

I have a simple block that shows the most recent posts. But I want the number of posts to be changeable. To do that, I created a simple attribute and integrate it with a range control.

```
const onChangePosts = ( newContent ) => {
    setAttributes( { numberPosts: newContent } );
};

<RangeControl
    value={ attributes.numberPosts }
    onChange={ ( value ) => onChangePosts( value ) }
    min={ 1 }
    max={ 10 }
/>
```

And here I'm getting the posts:

```
const posts = useSelect( ( select ) => {
    return select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords(
        'postType',
        'post',
        {
            'per_page': attributes.numberPosts
        }
    );
}, [] );
```

But when I update the attribute, the number of posts rendered in the block don't change.

The is the complete `Edit` function:

```
export default function Edit( { attributes, setAttributes  } ) {
    const posts = useSelect( ( select ) => {
        return select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords(
            'postType',
            'post',
            {
                'per_page': attributes.numberPosts
            }
        );
    }, [] );

    const onChangePosts = ( newContent ) => {
        setAttributes( { numberPosts: newContent } );
    };

    return (
        <div { ...useBlockProps() }>
            <InspectorControls key="setting">
                <Panel>
                    <PanelBody title="Number of posts">
                        <RangeControl
                            value={ attributes.numberPosts }
                            onChange={ ( value ) => onChangePosts( value ) }
                            min={ 1 }
                            max={ 10 }
                        />
                    </PanelBody>
                </Panel>
            </InspectorControls>
            { ! posts && 'Loading' }
            { posts && posts.length === 0 && 'No Posts' }
            <ul>
            { posts && posts.length > 0 && posts.map(post => (
                <li>
                    <a href={ post.link }>
                        { post.title.rendered }
                    </a>
                </li>
            ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

index.js file:

```
registerBlockType( 'create-block/dynamic-block', {
    /**
     * @see ./edit.js
     */
    edit: Edit,
} );
```

block.json file:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "create-block/dynamic-block",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "Dynamic Block",
    "category": "widgets",
    "icon": "smiley",
    "description": "Example static block scaffolded with Create Block tool.",
    "supports": {
        "html": false
    },
    "textdomain": "dynamic-block",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": "file:./style-index.css",
    "attributes": {
        "numberPosts" : {
            "type": "integer",
            "default": 3
        }
    }
}
```

Plugin init file:

```
function create_block_dynamic_block_block_init() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build', [
        'render_callback' => "gutenberg_examples_dynamic_render_callback",
    ]);
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_block_dynamic_block_block_init' );

function gutenberg_examples_dynamic_render_callback( $block_attributes, $content ) {
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => $block_attributes['numberPosts'],
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    ) );

    if ( count( $recent_posts ) === 0 ) {
        return 'No posts';
    }

    $posts = '';
    foreach ($recent_posts as $post) {
        $post_id = $post['ID'];
        $posts .= sprintf(
            '<p><a class="wp-block-my-plugin-latest-post" href="%1$s">#%2$s</a></p>',
            esc_url( get_permalink( $post_id ) ),
            esc_html( get_the_title( $post_id ) )
        );
    }

    return $posts;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your `registerBlockType()` (i.e. block type registration) code?

Comment: @SallyCJ I updated thje code. BTW, the block is using the structure generated by `@wordpress/create-block`

Comment: Thanks, but actually, I wanted to see your attributes list, i.e. `attributes: { the list here }` that's passed to `registerBlockType()`. And is this actually a dynamic block? If so, what's your full `register_block_type()` code?

Comment: @SallyCJ I updated the code. The PHP part is working fine. I'm able to get the correct value from `numberPosts` attribute. The problem is: in the editor, when I change the number of posts, the block is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

> when I update the attribute, the number of posts rendered in the block
> don't change

Yes, and that's because you did not include the `numberPosts` attribute in the **second parameter** (which is an *array of dependencies*) for `useSelect()`, so the ([memoized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)) value remains unchanged, even when the block's state is changed, or that you selected a new number of posts via the range control.

So your `useSelect()` should include the above dependency, i.e. use `[ attributes.numberPosts ]` instead of `[]` as the 2nd parameter, like so:

```js
const posts = useSelect( ( select ) => {
    return select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords(
        'postType',
        'post',
        {
            'per_page': attributes.numberPosts
        }
    );
}, [ attributes.numberPosts ] ); // here, make sure you include all dependencies
```

Additionally, you should set a [`key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) for your list items, e.g. `` <li key={ `post-${ post.id }` }> ``.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I tested but unfortunately it's not working. If I add a `console.log(attributes.numberPosts);` inside `const posts`, the value doesn't change when I update the number of posts.